# Passing cucumber options with Autotest and Bundler for Rails3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

I'm little confused on how to use cuke's options.

I know that I can run spec and cucumber in two different console. But I want it to run both.
So, I can pass args/options for rspec like `bundle exec autotest -c -f specdoc` but if I pass cucumber options like `--tags @wip --format pretty`, it blows out.

So, how can I accomplish this??

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02@automation [~/rails_apps/automation (refactor)⚡] ➔ bundle exec autotest -c --tags @wip
/Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1450:in `complete': invalid option: --tags (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in `catch'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1448:in `complete'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1261:in `parse_in_order'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `catch'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `parse_in_order'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in `order!'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in `permute!'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in `parse!'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@automation/gems/autotest-4.3.2/bin/autotest:6
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@automation/bin/autotest:19:in `load'
        from /Users/millisami/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@automation/bin/autotest:19
ree-1.8.7-2010.02@automation [~/rails_apps/automation (refactor)⚡] ➔
```

Answer (score 0):

Options can be passed to Cucumber through [cucumber.yml](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/cucumberyml)

For example (from the linked page), by having this in your config/cucumber.yml:

```
default: --format profile features
html_report: --format progress --format html --out=features_report.html features
```

Don't forget to set the environment variable `AUTOFEATURE` to `true`

After that, autotest with no arguments should be all you need.

**EDIT**

From the [Autotest Integration](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/autotest-integration) page:

To change the way the features are run with autotest create two profiles in your cucumber.yml:

- autotest : Used when Autotest wants to run only the failing scenarios.
- autotest-all : Used when Autotest wants to run all the scenarios (after a red→green transition).

For example, to turn color on when features are run, you would add the following to your cucumber.yml file:

```
autotest: --color
autotest-all: --color
```

Comment: Well, I replaced my cucumber.yml to the above as you suggested, but its not taking the effect. Here is the screenshot: http://img.skitch.com/20100803-k1q6898tdfxha2ma1923mqf7mw.png

And I even tried out with `default: --format pretty` as well. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `autotest: --format pretty --color --tags @wip` to your config/cucumber.yml
2. Restart autotest

Autotest then should pick up all scenarios tagged 'wip'. I use this quite regularly, hope this helps.